# WCF hosted in Windows service: configuration file for port

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, web-config, app-config

I'm trying to host my WCF service in a WindowsService. 
Thanks to [simplified configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee530014(v=vs.110).aspx), no need to bother a lot about the config file content. I found how to adjust a bit the binding configuration (see below). But not how to set the default port.

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
       <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<!-- No <service> tag is necessary. But how to define port? -->

<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="http" binding="basicHttpBinding"/>
</protocolMapping>
```

Setting the port could be done in the code. But I think, break the logic of having a config file. My goal is to have a very simple C# code behind this WindowsService hosting mechanism. All the rest being in the config file. 
As simple as:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    this._host?.Close();

    this._host = new ServiceHost(typeof(IMyService));
    this._host.Open();
}
```

The only valuable resource I found on the internet is [this MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx#_Step_2:_Configure) which was written before simplified configuration was introduced.

How can I configure the default port in the config file in the simplified configuration context?

Comment: what if you specify <services>/<host>/<baseAddresses>/<add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8523/Service1" />.  This does not force you to specify all service stuff, but you could setup host and port

Comment: @Mimas it seems that there is not host allowed node inside services

Comment: Sorry. Yes, you can specify ``host`` only inside ``service``